# jquery plugin to display a 'clear' button in a search input box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am having trouble trying to find something I know that does exist. In some forms your can clear your textbox by clicking on a 'cross'. It looks like this[image]

I am looking for a JQuery plugin that can add that to a textbox for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hows this for an option:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/hQLzX/

So basically i've enclosed the input and `img` inside a `span`, which will act as the parent.

**UPDATE**

I've improved my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/apgws/

Still does the same thing except now you dont have to hard code it, jQuery will do it.

Comment: I like especially the 2nd option..makes it really flexible..thanks a lot!